# Match numbers between 900 and 950 in regex

Tags: php, regex

How can I match numbers between **900** and **950**?.

I have the following regex to match numbers 900-950 :

```
/9[0-5][0-9]{3}/
```

But it is also matching **955** in a string,

How can I fix it to match untill 900 to 950 only?

Comment: Only with alternation: `/^9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)$/`

Comment: 900 - 949 or 950 = `9[0-4]\d|950`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match `900`-`950` number range, use

```
^9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)$
```

Or, if it is inside a larger text

```
(?<!\d)9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)(?!\d)
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW1pN1/1)

The `^` is the start of string anchor, and `$` is the end of string anchor.

The `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind making sure the preceding symbol is not a digit. The `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure the next character is not a digit.

Using a non-capturing group `(?:...)` we avoid capturing what we do not need.

One more option: if the number is in-between non-word characters, you can leverage word boundaries:

```
\b9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)\b
```

Note that I am using `9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)`, not `(?:9[0-4][0-9]|950)`. Although the second one is more readable, it is less effecient from the performance point of view since `9(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)` involves less backtracking (i.e. it fails quicker if there is no match).

Comment: Sorrym wife is nagging, will be back and explain more

Comment: This solution is complex to understand, but it has the advantage to match the number only while the other answers will also match the two characters next to the number.

Comment: Indeed. Wife first. ;-)

Comment: @GuillaumeF.: Complexity is only seeming. Regex used here is really a basic one after you complete lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com). Back to looking after my daughter.

Comment: Thank you stribiz for this explained answer. It works and your ans gave me some new ideas to write my own regex for number range. I appriciate it.

Answer (score 4):

split it up into ORs:

```
/(9[0-4][0-9]|950)/
```

`9[0-4][0-9]` will match from 900 to 949

`950` covers your 950 case without going over

if you want to make sure NOT to match anything else (like you might not want to match 1950 and might only want to match 950 on its own):

```
/(?<![0-9])(9[0-4][0-9]|950)(?![0-9])/
```

`(?<![0-9])` means don't allow a number before and `(?![0-9])` means don't allow a number after (negative look behind and ahead)

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Factoring out common numbers in number ranges is not a good idea. It leads to confusion when the range gets odd and bigger.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest would be this:

```
/[^\d]9([0-4][0-9])|50[^\d]/
```

Comment: This will match `950` in `195000`.

Comment: Well, there were no other constraints, so to make sure its not part of a larger number I edited.  Can it be part of a word?  We may never know.